# Chop up my ASCII art

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

Let's say I've got some ASCII art:

```
          ___
        ,"---".
        :     ;
         `-.-'
          | |
          | |
          | |
       _.-\_/-._
    _ / |     | \ _
   / /   `---'   \ \
  /  `-----------'  \
 /,-""-.       ,-""-.\
( i-..-i       i-..-i )
|`|    |-------|    |'|
\ `-..-'  ,=.  `-..-'/
 `--------|=|-------'
          | |
          \ \
           ) ) hjw
          / /
         ( (
```

([Source](https://www.asciiart.eu/computers/joysticks))

But I want to focus on the cable of this joystick, because I actually want a picture of a garden path, leading up to a door.

```
 ,=.
-|=|-
 | |
 \ \
  ) )
 / /
( (
```

I could copy out line after line, I could use a text editor with block selection mode, or... I could write some code!

So, my code needs five arguments:

- A piece of ASCII art, a newline separated string.
- The X axis of the top-left corner (1-indexed, from left hand column, positive integer)
- The Y axis of the top-left corner (1-indexed, from top row, positive integer)
- Width of the resultant image (positive integer)
- Height of the resultant image (positive integer)

### Test Cases

ASCII image:

```
          ___
        ,"---".
        :     ;
         `-.-'
          | |
          | |
          | |
       _.-\_/-._
    _ / |     | \ _
   / /   `---'   \ \
  /  `-----------'  \
 /,-""-.       ,-""-.\
( i-..-i       i-..-i )
|`|    |-------|    |'|
\ `-..-'  ,=.  `-..-'/
 `--------|=|-------'
          | |
          \ \
           ) ) hjw
          / /
         ( (
```

#### Garden path

- X: 10
- Y: 15
- Width: 5
- Height: 7

Result:

```
 ,=.
-|=|-
 | |
 \ \
  ) )
 / /
( (
```

#### DB icon

- X: 3
- Y: 12
- Width: 6
- Height: 4

Output:

```
,-""-.
i-..-i
|    |
`-..-'
```

#### Alien Elder

- X: 9
- Y: 1
- Width: 7
- Height: 10

```
  ___
,"---".
:     ;
 `-.-'
  | |
  | |
  | |
.-\_/-.
|     |
 `---'
```

#### Signature

- X: 16
- Y: 19
- Width: 3
- Height: 1

```
hjw
```

### Rules

- Output can be given by [any convenient method](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963).
- Either a full program or a function are acceptable.
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

Comment: Can we take X and Y as 0-indexed?

Comment: Also, in testcase 1, `Y` should bew `15`, and in TC 2, `X` should be `3`

Comment: Can we assume the input is padded to a rectangle with spaces?

Comment: Can you add a test case where the original art doesn't use *both* single and double quotes, please? Also, I see no good reason to enforce 1-indexing here.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought of when I saw that ascii art, a garden path. I didn't think of anything else at all...

Comment: It seems many of the X and Y values are incorrect in the test cases (maybe some are 0 indexed?!) - at least: Y of Garden Path should be 15; X of DB Icon should be 3.

Comment: Can input be `[[X1,X2],[Y1,Y2]]` or `[[X1,Y1],[X2,Y2]]`?

Comment: @Shaggy just use a `9x9` grid of `1-9`, expected results should be obvious.

Comment: If it wasn't for the cable / garden path, I would think the original ascii art was an ostrich carrying a tray with two coffee cups on it.

Comment: This question is begging for an elisp answer...

Answer (score 22):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 1 [byte](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
＠
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjIw,i=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__,v=8)

It takes height, width, Y, X, and ASCII art as inputs, in that order.

Though almost everything about the ASCII art objects in Canvas is 0-indexed, `＠` is 1-indexed by some reason. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Expected answer from canvas :D (mb charcoal have something similar)

Comment: What sorcery is this!

Comment: @AJFaraday I mean, wouldn't you expect that a language specifically made for ASCII-art manipulation to not have a built-in to get a specific part of an ascii-art? :p

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>64</s> 62 bytes

```python
lambda I,x,y,w,h:[l[x-1:][:w]for l in I.split('\n')[y-1:][:h]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZHNboMwDMfveQorl4TKDqTrh8rEqac@AyDKtDGYKK26Sm0l3p0l4WuXSbMl4t/fYMf48ryV52bZFVHS1fnp7T2HAz7wiXcsw7iOH6TDNA7vaXG@Qg1VAwf1famrmxRJI7z42efLNO2qU/75ARFwzmGyLMvYGCMnIq4mDt3zdWI4kiIxI7TQ/ocyRUnmk@o7ZeCbZP9KAk7zjdvqRMKciXFmRaeMJsDJPhLnpMYbOzC6hIqUomrQB/BYe3St2qFID6JliZ1F2aIYKRjAZ3PHNhq/@Xvg4aKTecbLr/svyQw2kwRpfj1jdlN7uympA9RrXOPWQ/mCeokbXJlwhxq3qAMT6g3qHZqcFzKYVlxIt0tc7K0Ml2vV3KBmrI@GQ5BYrIJR634A)

---

If `X` and `Y` can be `0`-indexed:

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 56 bytes

```python
lambda I,x,y,w,h:[l[x:x+w]for l in I.split('\n')[y:y+h]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZHNbsIwDMfveQorl6Rgp4TBYJ164sQzUBSYNtZOpSCG1Fbqu3dJ@sEuk2ZLif@/tHYcX@t7einm7SlO2vx4fns/whYrrLHENNrluyqqpuX@dLlBDlkBW/V9zbO7FEkhgl0d1dN0v2@z8/HzA2LgnMNoxhg2xMiJiKtRR359HTUcSJF4SGig@Y8yihITkuoqGQjtYfdJAp6F1l12ImH3xDpz0JPBBHgcInFOarixF5ZLyEgpynrei4A1B1@q6ZN0QjQscb0olxRjBb0I2aNiEw///N1wf9HRAuvpV/kL2cYeSoK0T8@YG9PGjUm@oF7gElcByjlqjc@4sOEaZ7hCPbOhXqJe4xPqIGIwjvck/ShxsnEYrresuEPOWBf1myAxWcwG1v4A)

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 7 bytes

```
δＪθηＴζε
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZDJCgIxDIbvfYrQy3SgSfEgooMv4MmDNytVVJgR18EFpO9eM53Ni2BSWr4/bZZu8025vWyOIczL4nxXuzQTs8fpuriom4acaVEWJ/XWsE@zEJZjDYOhBl4jDaWUUkBnzrmOtERESR1P4p71t9dImHw99uD/IUdonUGqKzkwHKyvWIiaYa@yIyZ8WrCi0qLQGgdYNRqlRGr7jWCFggKJsGjkBlLh17GOb1LUkHhhq0GoSqmnBA0Y0dfz0/bN72nrLjtL2fPD60vioXpSoAR//Crg8/gB) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes 0-indexed coordintaes. Explanation:

```
δ
```

Print the ASCII art.

```
Ｊθη
```

Jump to the top left corner of the desired rectangle.

```
Ｔζε
```

Trim the canvas to the desired size.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>21</s> 19 bytes

```
UV¶¡εXG¦}Y£}sG¦}s£»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZC9CgIxDMf3PEXocndwSXU4BOVmn0BRKFQFwXNxuMGlPowIvoEubn0AX6m2vS8XwQTa/P5pk6anerur9s4tlvZpr@/Ham7vl7W9XeoQ1PZmX86NR1CAEAJ701pDF@eCiAT3PI3rrGfcEFMyIBo0/5BmUloSN500Sp9sjiiMmvQeqhMlfleoIGhR6MwnvCpzEoK4e28EBSlWxExVK7eQgdnEPqYt0UBiQIVBOJTMS8YWJAz9TNnd@T1t88reMu@H4/lL8kMNlGLqvx3GBUw@)

Or if `0-indexing is allowed`:

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 18 bytes

```
UV¶¡εX.$Y£}sF¦}s£»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZBLCsIwEIb3c4ohCG2hM0FQRKVbb6AoBFIFwbpx0YWb9DBS8Aa6cZcDeKWapi83gjOQ5PsnmUcu@f6QHatqvbFPe3s/tjza2bLIV/Ze5La0r6qawxSEENib1hq6cyyISHDPC78ue8aUmIIB0aD5hzST0pK4qaRRumBzRaHXpPM6O1HgdoUKas0LnbmAU2VMQhB3/XpQEGJGzJS1cgsRmNTXMW2KBgIDqh6E65RxwtiChKGeSbo3v6dtuuwtcn46X78kN9RAIYbu22E8gdkH)

Comment: 12 if you can take in `[X1, X2]` and `[Y1, Y2]` as `v³ŸNåiy²ŸèJ=`

Answer (score 3):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-n`, 21 bytes

```
_@>--b@<dM(a^n--c+,e)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY87DsIwDIb3nMLq0lb0d@iAkICiXoAbRKS8JMpQdWPJ3U2a9MGChC0l@X47fvRtL2LrI3CtD/dTdjl3wG1VPHIRQSc0m7VWTe8iAZDwzLtw7memBox0QXLk/iHLMFaDYydL2gdjiqGgae9DdSD1tyGjBi0Ik/mAV3WBJAFP8wYwKqMWzGhHeYRcuSb0cWOJCKlTZliEh5JFxTSCVks/V01/fm8bp5wt9/58vb@kuNQiZN6JpFxLuZGNbD8)

Or, if 0-indexing is allowed...

### Pip `-n`, **17 bytes**:

```
_@>b@<dM(a^nc+,e)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY/JCsIwEIbveYqhl7bYmSAo4lLpC/gGwdQNrIfSm5e8@5i9XgRnIMn3z2SWaZiYdXe8dof7qbqcx9uiedTMjCNDNq21SO@mQMSCMu/8uc8MPRKWM4IB8w9pQqUlUuikQdpgSFHgNWndVUcs7a1ACad5IZkNWFU2WBRIaV4PSlQwIBEOUY5QC9P7PiaWCFAaodwi5Eo2LUEEKeZ@pk1/fm8bpsxWW3@@3l9SWGoWKusAvOXlite8@QA)

#### Explanation

Takes all five arguments as command-line args.

```
                   a-e are the 5 cmdline args; n is newline
         a^n       Split a on newlines
              ,e   Range(e)
            c+     Add c to each element
        (       )  Use the resulting range(c,c+e) to slice into the list of lines
       M           To each line, map this function:
_                   The line
 @>b                Slice, keeping indices b and greater
    @<d             Slice, keeping indices less than d
                   Print, joining on newlines (-n flag)
```

---

The above solutions also assume the input is a perfect rectangle--i.e., the lines are all the same length. Otherwise, 2 extra bytes are needed (use `-l` instead of `-n`):

```
(Z(a^nZDsb+,d)c+,e)      0-indexed, 19 bytes
(Z(a^nZDs--b+,d)--c+,e)  1-indexed, 23 bytes
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) `-R`, <s>13</s> 11 bytes

```
·tWÉY ®tVÉX
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=t3RXyVkgrnRWyVg=&input=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)

2 bytes saved thanks to [Kamil Drakari](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/71434/kamil-drakari)

9 bytes if not for the unnecessary requirement that solutions use 1-based indexing.

```
·tWY ®tVX
```

---

### Explanation

```
                :Implicit input of string U and integers V=X, W=Y, X=Width & Y=Height
·               :Split U on newlines
 t              :Slice
  WÉ            : From 0-based index W-1
    Y           : To length Y
      ®         :Map
       t        :  Substring
        VÉ      :   From 0-based index V-1
          X     :   To length X
                :Implicitly join with newlines and output
```

Comment: In my testing, you can save [2 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=t3RZyVYgrnRYyVc=&input=IjEyMwo0NTYKNzg5IgoyCjIKMQoxCi1S) by switching the slice to `t`, and [another 2 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=t3RZViCudFhX&input=IjEyMwo0NTYKNzg5IgoyCjIKMAowCi1S) by 0 indexing. It might be worth waiting on the second one since OP hasn't clarified whether 0 indexing is acceptable, or fixed the test cases.

Comment: Nice one, @KamilDrakari - completely forgot the `t` method works on arrays, too.

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>70</s> 69 bytes

-1 Thanks @Shaggy for the `splice()` idea.

```javascript
(a,x,y,w,h)=>a.split`
`.map(q=>q.substr(x-1,w)).splice(--y,h).join`
`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY9hb4IwEIa/91c0fKFN7o51mxpH8Lv/oQllDifECQqbmvDfWSmCJrpkd03T5727vm2e/CTV6pCVNe6Kj7RdR61I4ARnOMJGRouEqnKb1YYZ@kpKsY8We6q@36v6IE6o4Cila1ilAvFsJygvsp3tbsNlZPgYcRyz4QweIno08pvbw5G5NkjoX5k3vPkPxYRaxwFS7xXzwFb7Hq25EwObzgDR7w7aLtbJvTaEz50eAHoe0vBuB1YXPEMizC76BSRrtHF@zeWWHvyGdTam67L3QkR8oIDd2DbRMPf314f3jiFtbvLjjWR/eCXBhWHhqthVxTalbfEp1mIJ6gnUBCYwk/K@@ALqGabw@qg2BwUzO/6opqag5t20lO0v)

The ASCII art given is annoying tbh

Comment: [69 bytes](https://tio.run/##jY/dbsIwDIXv8xRRb5pItrtuA8RQuecdIjUdK6MVo0C7FaS8e5emPyDBpNlRlO/Yzkny5Ccp16fsUOG@@EibTdSIBM5wgRq2MlomVB52WaWZpq/kII7R8kjl93tZnQTiGWopXcM6tXixE5QX2d52N4tVpPkYcRyz4QweIno08pvbFyNzpZHQvzI33PyHYkKl4gCp84p5YKtdj1LciYFNZ4DotwdlF2vlThvC504PAD0PaXi3A6sLniERZr3eg2RGaedn@ls68A1rbXTbZe@FiPhAAbuxNdEw9/fXh/eOIW1u8/pGsj@8kuBCs8W62JfFLqVd8Sk2YgXhE4QTmMBMyvviC4TPMIXXR7U5hDCz449q4RTCeTstZfML)

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 45 bytes

```
f=:4 :0
'a b c d'=.x-#:10
y{~<(a+i.b);c+i.d
)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY/bTsMwDIbv@xS/mgu3rHZb2EBqqcSDBGVdx7TuZpeACLx6SZMeEBIStpT4@235cBmGU1NtURURtTigw5EaeWNVlUX0/vH1mLSbXg5p3bnvGKVD2whhMWOMmuMsZuZYFq78Wy@MPQsTrQwL@x8ywtrkLGGUQe6SoUTDa7nzsT279i7Q0GoUvTLbmHFynnEcs8wre9AqQc8i3E/yBKmyez/JTj0CEFmlx2PEN80awUy5Wmfaxi6j/7wyrLpY6vx8ef0hudNWSpBQ9NKdryh3eEBZYIcTPuXpuZaSFGVtyNJNsLn4Flvc4f5X7fAN)

Notes:
[J](http://jsoftware.com/) accepts up to 2 arguments, left and right. The right argument is the ASCII art string, the left one - a list of U H X W values

I simulate the newline and the function call has a code to convert the string to an array.

Answer (score 2):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 16 bytes

```
ÀGÀ|<C-v>@cl@djyHVGp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZC/CsIwEMb3PoDzkaUt9BI7qKAUutUncAqkoIMtDk6KkKHv1gc70/xpxSyC90HI98txd7kH0Tg046BX9flWX/rX8dTciWAOpdRiknApGCIyHvG9PQ8RhxY5pnEdAG30N1ccpRLI1SdXIHyuBgkqcGE0zYN2HmlkuXAsRDo9GS4KZAzDR52RkGTQIefYee5NnujWdtS@ijOpTuS0ALuBouLgjTD155660kvrH/bgBo855EbX/vnN3bej/MxoCSq3VK5pQ7s3)

Input is expected to be padded with spaces to be a perfect rectangle. Also, the 'Y' input comes before the 'X'.

Hexdump:

```
00000000: c047 c07c 1640 636c 4064 6a79 4856 4770  .G.|.@cl@djyHVGp
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <strike>118</strike> 109 bytes

The input can contain jagged lines: newlines are printed if they exist in the y-range.

Thanks to ceilingcat for the suggestion.

```c
f(s,x,y,w,h,a,b,c)char*s;{for(b=1,a=0;*s;a=c?!b++:a,s++)((c=*s==10)|++a>=x&a-x<w)&b>=y&b-y<h-c&&putchar(*s);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVNtb5swEP7Or7gyLTXBJsle21Jn2rR2mlRtH6Z9KlUKBgIThQjDkijw27Mzb0kmdZoJDvfcc3ePfbZgSyH2L@JUJKUfwLUs/Dizorl2AiWx9zeWx@kSsX1IJN3QLV3TiLrUo8IQkZuPpb0Ls5x4fEZdPrXRdrn4cOaZ5pVLpWkahAg@lpzPpkZlmu6cb0Yu21yvjZE359uRx7bXEROj0aosVEIyloZd79UnjJdB8VQmRUxuv97dwDg0YKcBtD5JQVDwyvD@YvrAd9PaRlecFgoSWZkWFFB894VYEqT8YmpryFKCJf/28@7uwOF9GC4CUHKItQUJDeOM33y/tdvKWCAkA5G3WXsXgOR54CZJJnCrhsRmx7J7UpGnYrUl0jyR12s85rXxXZkeP9LZILXWofe9xzQfuFBO5ToS3At9VmbLatP@S@aBV6vtzIOizFOQtoYmsktRgMiy3JdH7fIDKfoObShsKawpRBiCHVHYkxun5HcW@yc95sMJUOe13ZzTCm6ei3vsfyN6p39xcz9IYeUWkU5hNsX3LQX8va9pR/n8CWKRpeh@jd5XFN5ReDN4PyYxxgeJH@TIuEQGxqpMA@NHvExdXHGgCmDs7LLN1BPac8Vmx6/qRE1hLIbzJ7hSboNg82ZrQOBdORwycdb4DcBrIYnupHrXlxXexyIk@kvppI5aRJegc6tbqqBNM2@bed3MkdEfiTAPAoK3TKv3MIzFYqH131RnjOnWYF81sz3Y8Mgsdn4woYLqf6yFxZzFhFltpQVM0NlSHGiwCT4qO2Pn@O@AoymsAfqBDkQnlOk6s3q9jeFoBGJmWSzu4M4wtOqxqVN1KVrjvNIctRBLpaTcgs6YaId6Fe9jnl9tq3IYBj7Rr/URhIs6WATIHw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
Ỵṫ€¥ṫḣ€ḣ4ƭ/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZA7CgIxEIb7nGLYJitkJgqKoHgQMRIbQcXKRoRUNh5ErNTOQrFT8B7rReIk@7IRnDy/P8k8spgulxvvs/slux3f29PjwGt23fOW5/brrP1zN/R@tJJSQmXWWlHuVYKICVXci3O/YpggoawRHLh/yBIaq5HySBY0H@ZXDERNcwveEUNmBowIWhRK4wNWtcIkQSrzjWBECnMkwnkhF9AQbhLjuMJFDtIJEwqh4FINCArQoo7nBuWb39XmWVbW4DZbrL8kLqqmFFL@dgWtJo@OAu7d8Qc)

Takes the ASCII-art as a Python multi-line r-string (so as to avoid problems with backslashes).

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 61 bytes

```hs
(x#y)w h=unlines.map(take w.drop(x-1)).take h.drop(y-1).lines
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY9Lb4MwEITv/hUjUilGyi51H6nSllOvvfWKRJCCCk3iRIGIROK/08U80kNTdY2A@XY8a2dJsU43m6bRp8nZr5CFR7vJbVrwNtnrMlmnqHh12O31iYzvsyNZR85C2JmbbZJbhFjtFKRyuz@WeCV8puXbzpapLQvlOsI/ysO7xQ30xIe5hXkE5HnqNv1mwj3MHTAHHv4wLQDTxkjkVZOZwyzaPLE6U4Ox4jhWw//MIyKPR/3s3i@jxpKYpheJGvV/VMwUxQFxNylGIM3OEsGxQFabTjSVb4RItcyBoaQhNJiR5xEP53UiUho5MVPe4174ql66OXUf0YlpraL2ItxGzkJGLwJ1mVeHw57rt@1OOZYvK/uqfiC51EVp6G8)

Takes arguments in order: `x`, `y`, `w`, `h`, `s`.

Comment: 58 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jU/LbsIwELz7K0ahCFvKbuo@qGibU6@99RopBBE1KeAgCAKk/HvqOA96KFXXlu2ZnZ31Zsl@la7XdS1Po7M6IgsPZp2bdM@bZCuP45NimY3Pih0pkvEiLJNVioSXu2IrF6RVvUlygxDLQsBGbraHEq@Ez7R8K0yZmnIvXMbyH@Xu3eAGcqSgb6EfAbuf2qLfRLiHvgOmwMMfohmgGxtreVWkp9Czxs9KnajGEHEci/7te0Tk8YCf3fkyYMyJaXKBqFD9B8VMURwQt51iBDbZSiI4LrCrcSea2DtCJBrOEX3YhGUDnzyPuP@vA5GQyImZ8o7ugBLV3PWpOosWTCoRNYNwY@mHjA4E4tKvCvua69O2vxxC2ZV9HX9QdqgLkpDf "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + coreutils, 37

```bash
cut -b$1-$[$1+$3-1]|tail +$2|head -$4
```

Interestingly, GNU tail 8.28 (on Ubuntu 18.04) allows `+NUM` format, whereas GNU tail 8.29 on TIO requires 2 extra bytes for this `-n+NUM`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZLLTsMwEEX3/oorK1JStePUfaovdrBlw46gNE1TJQU1EjEChPn2MHk0LQskxpLjc8e@47Gyi4q0jCODGxzzz8Jk8bMyHwbrNdzb@ztXoIswDDsaSCKSquNlPa8uu7ek6Pqwhf0PhYqC0CfVVArhc7LZEqDWfB6VO5HL3wCBqLRaOAcnWPUHJCWp831rCISHjJSirJVb6Am7revY1qIB14qgakRVloONQgu@uNSzm/OZv7ttbtlFj0d6fL@SuKkLefAEv7wQB6@HrzJ@M6Cdo8l5dHTfGZN@sibKXkCnvjOyaRLtQc6k/BaH/BUmKQyyE6QeQk8xxVxCjqFHmGHCywU05tBDXuoZ9AKckyvsc66fxGkO@cAOcVQkcCqvpQRnDg1g/esfEfv8lJQ/)

I thought doing this all in `sed` might be shorter, but at 50 bytes its not:

```bash
sed -nr "$2,$[$2+$4-1]s/.{$[$1-1]}(.{,$3}).*/\1/p"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 62 bytes

Perhaps surprisingly short solution to a text challenge in R, because we don't need to actually read the whole text into a matrix.

```r
function(x,y,w,h)write(substr(readLines()[y+1:h-1],x,x+w-1),1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY9LboMwEIb3PoVFFtjKjInbJlFScYPeoFSEFAiuKrcyIIjE3anNK9lUyoxk6//mbfo87PNaf1bqR7MWrtBAwRujqoyV9bmsDDNZkr4pnZWMv1/X8lig/IAW2nWDkoPk/SpncgNyC1vYc7qil8Skmaa/SVUQG3sG@QQ7eHGh9OyI3IE8gOUOleqik6o2GcnZASTsQW4cT75VpgldLI7jRYGHiJ5Y9HF4X2/ZJxTo3xV3tHtExQKjOEAxToppYINjSkQHFlh33RF9@0c0Io4NYDYbsDQA9DwU876DiAijCoVANeFJcNKdhjnd1GIUfkcid4hwLSEUdBIBuc3rwrnm/2vHLRfj1ouv5g7Zo26KUUb6Pw)

Answer (score 1):

## [K4](http://kx.com/download/), 31 bytes

**Solution:**

```
{[a;x;y;w;h]a .-1+(y;x)+!:'h,w}
```

**Examples:**

```
q)ASCII:("          ___";"        ,\"---\".";"        :     ;";"         `-.-'";"          | |";"          | |";"          | |";"       _.-\\_/-._";"    _ / |     | \\ _";"   / /   `---'   \\ \\";"  /  `-----------'  \\";" /,-\"\"-.       ,-\"\"-.\\";"( i-..-i       i-..-i )";"|`|    |-------|    |'|";"\\ `-..-'  ,=.  `-..-'/";" `--------|=|-------'";"          | |";"          \\ \\";"           ) ) hjw";"          / /";"         ( (")
q)k){[a;x;y;w;h]a .-1+(y;x)+!:'h,w}[ASCII;10;15;5;7]
" ,=. "
"-|=|-"
" | | "
" \\ \\ "
"  ) )"
" / / "
"( (  "
q)k){[a;x;y;w;h].[a;-1+(y;x)+!:'h,w]}[ASCII;3;12;6;4]
",-\"\"-."
"i-..-i"
"|    |"
"`-..-'"
q)k){[a;x;y;w;h].[a;-1+(y;x)+!:'h,w]}[ASCII;9;1;7;10]
"  ___  "
",\"---\"."
":     ;"
" `-.-' "
"  | |  "
"  | |  "
"  | |  "
".-\\_/-."
"|     |"
" `---' "
q)k){[a;x;y;w;h].[a;-1+(y;x)+!:'h,w]}[ASCII;16;19;3;1]
"hjw"
```

**Explanation:**

Take the 1-indexed input, generate the x/y coordinates and index into ascii art.

```
{[a;x;y;w;h]a .-1+(y;x)+!:'h,w} / the solution
{[a;x;y;w;h]                  } / lambda taking 5 inputs, a(scii), x, y, w(idth), h(eight)
                           h,w  / concatenate height and width, e.g. 7 5
                        !:'     / range til each, e.g. (0 1 2 3 4 5 6;0 1 2 3 4)
                  (y;x)+        / add list y x to it, e.g. (15 16 17 18 19 20 21;10 11 12 13 14)
               -1+              / subtract 1, e.g. (14 15 16 17 18 19 20;9 10 11 12 13)
            a .                 / index into a at these coordinates
```

Answer (score 1):

## [\/\/>](https://github.com/torcado194/worm/), 123 bytes

```
j:j8+}j+}j}pppp80x
{:}i:0(?v:a=?x@s1+:
~~~~1+0!/000y
yp:qqqq~
q{y?=p:+1q:}}g$q:pp:
1}x}p}ap:q~q+1{{y!?:-
ys{{
~!u.*2(0:;!?h
```

Input consists of a single line of space-delimited input variables `x`, `y`, `w`, and `h`, followed by the ascii art on the next line onward.

### Explanation

This code uses \/\/>'s ability to self-modify by placing the ascii art in the code itself, which ends up looking like this:

[image: code]

It then grabs the characters in the specified rectangle off of the code and outputs it.